# Return a value in generated java code in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

i am writing a grammar in ANTLR and i want to make a question about return values. I have this rule:

```
mainParser returns [int test]
    :
    triple EOF 
         {
            $test = 0;
         }
    ;
```

When i call it from generated java code i can't take back the test value, because it returns me a "parser object": [image]

How to make it to return Integer, String etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mainParser must return a tree *and* an int, it must use an object.  That mainParser_return object has both, if you look inside.

Comment: I can believe it! It was in front of my eyes..i was creating a return object and it gave me the tree but i did't go farther (for some stupid reason). Thanks a lot!!!